# Did Gauss ever make a mistake?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I have read a bit about Gauss, who was well known for being careful in only publishing work he had perfected (or in his own words "few, but ripe"). What is interesting to me about Gauss though is that all accounts of his students and contemporaries essentially make him appear flawless. Dedekind's recollections of how whenever Gauss wrote out an argument he used exactly the amount of space he had available, etc. In Disquistiones Arithmeticae, Gauss for example points out the flaws and shortcomings of other famous mathematicians such as Euler, who some might rank close to Gauss.

So I am curious if there is a single recorded instance of Gauss ever having made a mathematical error.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: (Tongue firmly in cheek) Gauss was a pioneer in the theory of errors ... [the Gauss error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one record that I'm aware of in which Gauss effectively concedes to having made a mathematical error, although it appears in casual correspondence rather than in publication.  This correspondence involved some recreational mathematics involving the eight-queens problem that was posed when Gauss was in his 70s.  In that correspondence, Gauss asks that his value of 76 confirmed solutions be reduced to 72 (although he correctly asserts that there may be others, as the full answer is 92).  Details of this episode can be found in the article [*"Gauss and the eight queens problem: A study in miniature of the propagation of historical error"*](http://langevin.univ-tln.fr/cours/PAA/tps/backtrack/histo-gauss.pdf) by
Paul J. Campbell (1977).

Answer (score 12):

You are seeing the down side of the "few but ripe" idea. He comes off badly in the episode with Bolyai. He did not publish his findings n a new, non-Euclidean geometry, over [fears of shrill criticism from followers of Immanuel Kant](http://books.google.com/books?id=uCYPZ4nRqy0C&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=gauss%20howls%20of%20the%20boeotians&source=bl&ots=5k8aT-rYIl&sig=FKXZzoyW-dx6TQT__gyRdmaHhgk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pt-XUvLZAem8jALgpICoBg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=gauss%20howls%20of%20the%20boeotians&f=false). For the moment, I am going to assume that the word he actually used referred to [Boethius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boethius); perhaps someone else knows. EDIT: no, it is an ancient insult, [the citizens of Athens thought of their neighbors as dull and stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeotia#Pejorative_term).

The part I dislike is when Janos Bolyai's father, Farkas Bolyai, wrote to Gauss, asking his opinion of this new world. Gauss replied that he could not praise Janos, as he would then be praising himself, Gauss having done much the same thing decades earlier. I've always thought this a mixture of cowardice and lack of generosity. There really is a difference between doing a bunch of calculations and saying "If so and so happens, here are some rules that apply" compared with saying "Here is the actual thing."

Well, the full story is intricate, but Gauss's reply hit Janos very hard, and appears to have convinced him to drop mathematics; at least, he published no more.

Comment: I cannot but remember with this incident what [Stephen Hawking said to Homer Simpson](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/They_Saved_Lisa%27s_Brain/References).

Comment: Gauss also rejected Abel's work on the general solution of a quintic equation.

Answer (score 10):

Euler ranks higher than Gauss in my opinion.  Having said that, I do not know if there is a recorded instance of Gauss making a mathematical error, but it's worth pointing out that the work of the 18th and early 19th century mathematicians was plagued by lack of rigor.  Only later in the 18th century did the strides in analysis give mathematics a solid grounding.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. I have no idea how "rigorous" Gauss's works appear to mathematicians today reading them. I wonder if anyone has ever done a study from such a perspective.

Comment: @MattBrenneman To mathematicians today, Gauss is a giant regardless. Gaps or lack of rigor in his work by no means diminish its importance and originality. Listen to this podcast if you are interested: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00ss0lf

Comment: Second only to Euler, I would say.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do not forget Laplace, the man who gave us the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Oh, there are (were?) many giants. But I think the first two places are settled (well, maybe some day...).

Comment: My vote goes to Grothendieck! :)

Comment: @Ioannis  Thanks for the nice podcast! I never heard of du Sautoy before, but he does such a nice job of taking a very broad subject, singling out one interesting example, and then explaining it well.

Comment: @Peter Hey there... what is a stereotypical number theorist? ;)

Comment: @PeterSheldrick The credit for Least Squares goes to Legendre, Laplace is famous for initiating Bayesian Statistics amongst others.

Comment: @Ioannis : did any 18th or early 19th century mathematicians notice or comment on the lack of rigor of their peers' work?

Comment: @StefanSmith I'd say so. Laplace viciously criticized Fourier for lack of rigor.

Comment: @Ioannis In fact, many mathematicians blasted Fourier for his work. He shot from the hips in somewhat the same fashion as Newton and Leibniz with regards to developing calculus, taking things for granted. Fourier died fairly young I believe (40s?) and he never got to see his work vindicated. Kind of tragic if you ask me.

Comment: "Christmas in the clouds movie has no goofs, but in my opinion, Inception is the best."

Comment: @DanielFischer My TA mentioned that if Galois and Abel lived to be older, they would be bigger names than Euler. Just curious if you have an opinion on that?

Answer (score 3):

how about errors of omission? Gauss was famous for not publishing monumental discoveries until after they were rediscovered.